# Twig: how to get values from [someName:protected]?

Tags: theming, 9

When I kint:

```
{{ kint(elements.steps[0].step.description['#object']) }}
```

I get:

```
...
[activities:protected] => Array
    (
       (
        [17] => stdClass Object
            (
                [__CLASS__] => stdClass
                [id] => 17
                [vid] => 17
                [type] => opigno_video
                [name] => Dzień 1
                [usage_activity] => local
                [skills_list] => 
                [skill_level] => 
                [activity_status] => 1
                [weight] => -1000
                [max_score] => 10
                [auto_update_max_score] => 0
                [omr_id] => 25
                [omr_pid] => 
                [child_id] => 17
                [child_vid] => 17
            )
...
```

I would like to get all these activities, can I get them inside twig file?
I tried:

```
{{ kint(elements.steps[0].step.description['#object']->get('activities') }}
{{ kint(elements.steps[0].step.description['#object']->activities) }}
```

And some other options, but no result so far.

Comment: What's this step? What's this template? Sometimes easier to preprocess it into the template.

Comment: it´s a protected property, so you can only access this if there´s a public method in that class that returns the activities, pls find out which typeof #object is and check the source for methods